# Problem when adding a slider in the front page : admin panel works like I added a new slider

Tags: laravel

Not  working  add my slider in my  front page.. Admin panel working  like  I add new  slider. That is  working  but  front page  is  not  working.

> Undefined variable: sliders (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\resources\views\front\layouts\slider.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\resources\views\front\layouts\slider.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\resources\views\front\layouts\slider.blade.php)

[image: snap]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have defined a undefined variable at view. You may not passing the values into the variable from controller. So please update the question with the relevant controller and the code of the relevant view.

Comment: thank your  comment ..mam  thats  is  my  code  in  view  file ..whats  the  problem  i think i declare  the variable  properly

Comment: @foreach($sliders as $slider)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$slider->id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$slider->tittle}}</td>@endforeach

Comment: ok you may declare the variable properly but you may not passing the value in to variable via controller. Just check your controller

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $slider= new Slider();
        $slider->tittle = $request->tittle;
        $slider->url = $request->url();
        $slider->description = $request->description;
        $slider->status = 1;
if ($slider->save()){
            return redirect()->route('slider.index')->with('success','Slider Successfully Created');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('slider.index')->with('error','Slider Not Created');
        }

Comment: Look that you are not compacting variable **sliders ** in your function .So that view cannot find any variable named as **sliders*

Comment: show the code of route slider.index . You should compact your variable there